# How to use LIMIT to always include first row

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I'm wonder if there is way to use `LIMIT` operator to always include first row in result set. I mean regardless of any range specified. For Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 5, 10
```

should return first row and row 6 to 15 or:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 200, 30
```

should return first row and row 201 to 231. Is there a way to do that ?

**Edit** First row id is always 0

Comment: Actually, LIMIT 5, 10 returns rows 6-15, not 5-15...

Comment: @Pete: Right, just a mistake.

Comment: Do you know anything about the result set? Will the first element always have the lowest ID or something along those lines?

Comment: Be careful!  Formally speaking, the order of the rows in a SELECT statement result set is *unpredictable* unless you specify it with an ORDER BY clause.  That is, the MySQL server gets to decide which row is the first row. Right now it's deciding in your favor. Later it can change its mind.

Comment: @Scott: Yes, its id is always 0

Comment: @OllieJones: True, i know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see another way :

```
(SELECT * from table LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 10)
```

or as Pointed by Scott, with new infos ;)

```
SELECT * from table Where id = 0
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 10)
```

don't forget [brackets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) :

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10) UNION
>   (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);

Comment: How about heavy and large queries ?

Comment: As explained, **I** don't see another way. You might find another way with Ordering for a specific query, maybe...

Comment: According to the users comment, you can make this query slightly faster by changing the first part to "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id=0".

Comment: @Strawberry well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket : usage seems to exist ;) But I should have used "round brackets" to be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION to connect 2 selects: `(SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5, 10)`